# Text is messed up with ImageSpan in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring, spannable

I am building a simple chat app where the user has the ability to send text and emoticons. I can send both text and emoticons to another phone. My problems are:

**1.When I type something and add an emoticon:**

[image]

Then I cannot type any text right before and right after the image. I can write before the "o" letter. The system "sees" that I type, so even if I type "Honey" after the smiley, I cannot see it, but the EditText registers it and the message is sent:

[image]

**2.When I add just an emoticon to the Edittext then I delete it**, I cannot type anything because the deleted emoticon appears. It appears only once, so no matter how many characters I type, the EditText looks like just before I deleted the emoticon, BUT the text is sent without the emoticon, just like in all three cases.

**3.When I type "something" in the EditText then insert an emoticon after "some":**

[image]

Then I put the cursor after the emoticon and delete it, here what's left:

[image]

But the correct message is sent when I press the Send button:

[image]

That's what's inside the button listener of the emoticon (this method is activated when I click the emoticon to add it to the EditText).

```
ib_happy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int cursorPosition = mOutEditText.getSelectionStart();
            mOutEditText.getText().insert(cursorPosition, smileys[0]);
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(mOutEditText.getText());
        ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bitmapArray.get(0), ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE), cursorPosition,  cursorPosition+2, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        mOutEditText.setText(ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            mOutEditText.setSelection(cursorPosition+2);
        dialog_emoticon.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: where you able to fix it?

Comment: Yes I was as you see in the accepted answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. All I had to do was to change  `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE` to `Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE`

Comment: I have the same problem, but `Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE` does not solve the problem at my Jelly Bean device. At an Android 2.2 it works like expected. Do you have any information about that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't and I don't own a Jelly Bean device

Comment: @fish I've tested in Jelly Bean (emulator) and there's no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a textwatcher to that edittext and watch as the user types, that way I can reposition the images/set the text/make corrections/validate input/etc.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //editText.doStuffHere
        //reposition your image/etc.
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
};
```

Comment: So when I type hello:) /:) is the smiley/ txt count is 7. Then I type "Honey", which is invisible, but it's there because the number of typed characters has increased to 12. What can I do about this?

Comment: Sorry I'm in breadcrumb mode on this one. Perhaps something under afterTextChanged .... if (s.contains(":)")) and then under onTextChanged use the start, before, and count to reconstruct the text output by determining where the ":)"'s are and using editText.getText & editText.setText.