# ImageSpan removes following text at Android 4.2 Jelly Bean

Tags: android, textview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My problem is pretty similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867815/text-is-messed-up-with-imagespan-in-edittext). But it only appears when testing on a Android 4.2 device. On an older test device with Android 2.2 everything works quite nice.

**My problem**

I'm adding an ImageSpan in the middle of a TextView which shell replace one character of the TextView. At Android 4.2 *no text after the ImageSpan* will be shown. At Android 2.2 everything works like expected.

**Code Sample**

```
    CharSequence chars = txtView.getText();
    SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(chars);

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
        int codePoint = Character.codePointAt(chars, i);
        if (codePoint > 255) {
               // loading the bitmap ...
               ImageSpan img = new ImageSpan(context, bmp, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
               stringBuilder.replace(i, i + 1, "");
               stringBuilder.setSpan(img, i, i + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
    txtView.setText(stringBuilder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

**Screenshots**

[image: Android 2.2 Screenshot which shows how it should be]
[image: Android 4.2 Screen which shows the bug]

**What I've tried so far**

I tried nearly any [Spanned](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html)-Constant which you can add at `setSpan` but nothing works on the 4.2 device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really sorry that I posted this, cause I found the answer myself.
I really thought that I tried `Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE` before, but I obviously didn't. Anyway...

`stringBuilder.setSpan(img, i, i + 1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`

works for me at Android 4.2 and Android 2.2. Hopefully this thread will help someone else in the future.